# Xcode touchesEnded stops working

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touchesended

I am writing an app with Xcode and swift. I am using [SpriteKit's SKScene](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiM-fiVvPvWAhVp_IMKHXnUBZEQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdocumentation%2Fspritekit%2Fskscene&usg=AOvVaw3JdLIhmyVUmvXLzyDPO2WD). I am having a super interesting error. I have a class `Level1` and inside it, I have the `touchesEnded` method, and it works for about 2 or so clicks, and then it just stops. I have a simple `print("hello world")` in it, and it prints it twice, then stops. I don't really know what to attach for this error, so I have attached the method and the superclass method

```
import SpriteKit

class Level1: LevelBase {

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
        print("Hello world")
    }
}
```

and

```
import SpriteKit

class LevelBase: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

      override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            for node in nodes(at: location) {
                if node.name == "planet" {
                    moveAroundPlanet(planet: node as! SKSpriteNode)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding `Level1` from another scene using this

```
var scene = SKScene()
scene = Level1(fileNamed: "Level1")!
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
self.scene?.view?.presentScene(scene)
```

Let me know if any additional code is needed

Comment: have you checked if `touchesCancelled` is getting called in that case?

Comment: Something else is going on that removes the level1 scene from your game

Comment: @D4ttatraya I tried it with `touchesBegan`, and `touchesCancelled`, and all exhibit the same behavior. @KnightOfDragon I tried a global search for `remove` and the only thing that comes up is when I remove a SHShapeNode, and when I remove an action from one of my other nodes. IS there any way it would be getting removed without the `remove` line?

Comment: Doesnt have to be `remove`  something else can take be taken over the view scene, or level1 never actually gets called.  You aren't showing any code that replicates your problem.  Create a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and somebody will be better able to assist you.

Comment: you are using question marks.  how do we even know the scene is being presented?  It may be self.nil.nil.presentScene, which does nothing.  This is why MCVE is important, so that we may see exactly what steps you are taking.